# svcutil does not generate soap client

Tags: .net, soap, wsdl

I have a web service I would like to connect to and I can't figure out what goes wrong with the wsdl.

The wsdl is at "http://marketplacebylaredoute.fr/spapi/SellerOrderService?wsdl". I then try to run svcutil http://marketplacebylaredoute.fr/spapi/SellerOrderService?wsdl and it fails. 
The error is the following (extract only)

```
Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.Se
rviceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: These members may not be derived.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://Redcats/Order
/SellerOrder/2.0']/wsdl:portType[@name='portType']
```

Any idea what could be wrong with this wsdl ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [wsdl.exe Error: Unable to import binding '...' from namespace '...'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77534/wsdl-exe-error-unable-to-import-binding-from-namespace)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem comes from the `<wsdl:part>`s like this one:

```
<wsdl:part element="ns5:UpdateSellerOrderRequest_2.0" name="parameters">
```

When `name="parameters"`, svcutil.exe thinks that the service is doc/literal/wrapped.

If you change it to something else than `parameters`, svcutil.exe will interprete it as doc/literal/bare.

**The solution is:**

Use Fiddler to create a proxy that change `parameters` to `parameters1`.

Quick and dirty code for that:

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
    if (m_Hide304s && oSession.responseCode == 304) {
        oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
    }
    oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
    oSession.utilReplaceInResponse('parameters', 'parameters1');

}
```

Comment: After 2 days blaming wsdl.exe this worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome, Worked for me too finally !! . If you do not mind , how were you able to figure out this is the problem ?  Any tool ?

Comment: @Chandan it came from this blog post: http://webservices20.blogspot.fr/2010/01/interoperability-gotcha-these-members.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of Dave:
If you're using Visual Studio you can also change the parameters names to parameters1 by saving your wdsl and changing it locally.

Replace all parameters by parameters1

Add service reference by adding path to the myservice.wdsl file like c:\webserice\myservice.wdsl

You can find more answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77534/wsdl-exe-error-unable-to-import-binding-from-namespace)