# How To generate WCF for specific WSDL

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, wsdl

We have to call a specific soap webservice and are not able to generate the needed .NET Proxy classes. We tried to do it with the svcutil.exe as well as simply add the service reference in visual studio but we get the same errors. We just don't know what's wrong with this wsdl. The errors are:

> Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portTypeDetail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporterError: These members may not be derived.XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://localhost:8000/ibis/ws/Tasklist']/wsdl:portType[@name='TaskControl_-*WSC*-_MainPortType']
>
> Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:bindingDetail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://localhost:8000/ibis/ws/Tasklist']/wsdl:portType[@name='TaskControl_-*WSC*-*MainPortType']XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://localhost:8000/ibis/ws/Tasklist']/wsdl:binding[@name='TaskControl*-*WSC*-_MainBinding']
>
> Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portDetail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://localhost:8000/ibis/ws/Tasklist']/wsdl:binding[@name='TaskControl_-*WSC*-_MainBinding']XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://localhost:8000/ibis/ws/Tasklist']/wsdl:service[@name='externalinterfacetasks_v10']/wsdl:port[@name='TasklistPort']

SoapUi seems to have no problems with it.

The link to the problematic wsdl: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0PhgwgtgEbRX3U3c05WRW5LbU0

Does anybody have an idea what the problem is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682947/svcutil-does-not-generate-soap-client

Comment: If you can add the reference (.dll) in the client application using visual studio make sure you add the reference to the data member and data contract dlls as well if they are defined in a seperate assembly. Create a proxy class by extending ClientBase<IYourServiceContract> and set up the client config in C# or in app.config / web.config file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [svcutil does not generate soap client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682947/svcutil-does-not-generate-soap-client)

Comment: Not possible - it *is* a duplicate....

Answer (score 0):

The Comment from Yawar Murtaza is the solution:

- [svcutil does not generate soap client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682947/svcutil-does-not-generate-soap-client)

We just renamed "Parameters" to "Parameters1" and it worked.

Thank you !